# How to access session set through zf2 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework2

I have an website built in wordpress and a member section built in zf2. Now i want to access logged in user details in wordpress but there is no direct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by adding autoload file in index.php like :

```
include('./vendor/autoload.php'); // my autoload file is in vendor as i have installed zf2 throgh composer, update it accordingly
```

and you can access your session like :

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
$session = new Container('SESSION_CONTAINER_NAME');
```

it worked for me.

Comment: you're asking and answering your question?

Comment: Yeah as i have searched alot on google but there is no proper answer posted anywhere. I have posted this on stackoverflow, so that it can help others.